# Can't reply to comments

Tags: comments

I can't approve or reply to comments via the dashboard. Approving just returns the comments. And quick reply doesn't work and it says page not found and shows a whole bunch of code in red, nothing too obvious.

I deactivated all the plugins but still doesn't work.

So I'm guessing a file is missing because it says so but doesn't say which page is missing.

Here is part of the code that is returned as screenshot.[image]

Comment: Replace your `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` folder with WordPress core folder. May be it will solve your problem.

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya do you mean replace those folders with new ones?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: thanks just did that, it didn't fix but I found that my admin-ajax.php is empty and im not able to transfer it or upload a new copy.

Comment: You can delete your `admin-ajax.php` file and then reupload it

Comment: yes thank you, that lead me to the resolution. It is now working, so the admin-ajax.php was corrupt for some reason now that I've replaced it, all working again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Solution.This will surely helps you.

Replace your `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` folder with WordPress's core folder from WordPress package. May be you have problem with uploading these two folders and this may lead you that problem.

Comment: It's not the actual answer so not accepting but voted up. Thank you!

Comment: If its resolved your issue, then its actual answer.